# What is the rule for taking the matrix derivative of an inverse?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normal-distribution, inverse

I am looking for a rule giving a general solution for

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} a^T X^{-1} b$$

with $X$ a square matrix. Moreover, I would be interested how this rule differs if $X$ is symmetric.

From [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) I know

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} a^T X b = ab^T$$

as well as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} a^T X^T b = b a^T$$

but I am not sure how these results may be of help here.

Specifically, this result is needed when taking the derivative of a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with respect to $\Sigma$ in

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma} (2\pi)^{-D/2} \det (\Sigma)^{-1/2} \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \big)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to rewrite the function, then find its differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= ab^T:X^{-1} \cr\cr
df &= ab^T:dX^{-1} \cr
   &= -ab^T:X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} \cr
   &= -X^{-T}ab^TX^{-T}:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= -X^{-T}ab^TX^{-T} \cr\cr
}$$
The only tricky bit is knowing that $$dX^{-1}=-X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}$$ which can be derived by considering the differential of $\,\,I=X^{-1}X$

This result is for the general case. If you impose a symmetry constraint on  $X$ then you should modify the result to
$${\rm csym}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\Big)$$
where 
$${\rm csym}(A)=A+A^T-{\rm diag}(A)$$ 
For details on why this particular symmetrization is needed, see the "Structured Matrices" section in the Matrix Cookbook.